# Modifying menu items

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a popup menu I would like to modify before it is being displayed. I can actually modify the string of a menu item fine. The problem is, that this renders it useless as nothing happens when the modified menu item is clicked on.

```
CMenu* pPopup = menu.GetSubMenu(0);
ASSERT(pPopup != NULL);

CWnd* pWndPopupOwner = this;
while(pWndPopupOwner->GetStyle() & WS_CHILD)
    pWndPopupOwner = pWndPopupOwner->GetParent();

// modify string
pPopup->ModifyMenu(1, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_STRING, NULL, oss.str().c_str());

pPopup->TrackPopupMenu(TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON, point.x, point.y, pWndPopupOwner);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to `ModifyMenu` is setting the menu's ID to zero (via the third argument).  You need to keep that ID the same.

If that's awkward, the `SetMenuItemInfo` API lets you change the string without changing the ID.