# Changing MFC Menu Popup text in C++

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I'm writing an MFC C++ application.  I have the following menu in my main window.  I am trying to change the text via C++ for the FIRST POPUP item entitled "&File".  How can I do this?

```
IDR_ISOPROTYPE MENU
BEGIN
    POPUP "&File"
    BEGIN
        POPUP "second"
        BEGIN
            MENUITEM "third",                   ID_33280
        END
        MENUITEM "&Open...\tCtrl+O",            ID_FILE_OPEN
        MENUITEM "Rever&t",                     ID_FILE_REVERT
```

Comment: Try to update the menu item from the [CWnd::OnInitMenu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#oninitmenu) callback, although I'm not sure it is invoked for a menu bar (as opposed to popup menus).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modifying menu items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796341/modifying-menu-items)

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. I have code to change the text of a menu item which works great, but it doesn't seem to work in this situation where I have a CMFCPopupMenu inside of the CMDIFrameWndEx::OnShowPopupMenu override. By "doesn't work", I mean it does absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 0):

First, get the [handle to the menu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmenu), like

```
HMENU hMenu = GetMenu(AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd->GetSafeHwnd());
```

Then, call the ModifyMenu function

```
ModifyMenu(hMenu, 0, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_STRING, 0, "New&File");
```

If you need to modify the text of a submenu, you can still use the ModifyMenu function, but using a submenu handle

```
HMENU hSubMenu = GetSubMenu(hMenu, 1);
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for me.  Would you be open to helping via a screen share?  I'm in Atlanta, GA USA.  I can be reached via email at danielgifford@gmail.com.  I will post the answer here to benefit everyone.  I hear you are in France.  I'm sorry for your loss (Notre Dame).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not into solving this via screen share -- can you elaborate on `Your solution doesn't work for me`? [I normally tell my programmers never to say "doesn't work", but to explain what doesn't work]